# Select row data from every last 5 minutes data from a csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, aggregate

Problem Statement:

I have a CSV file that has some records/rows for 30 minutes. I need to create another CSV that will be having a row for every 5-minute interval considering we need to pick last not null values for a given column in that 5-minute interval.

Sample Data I have:

```
DateTime    A          B            C        D
0:00:00 502.8977051 503.2932129 18.44742966 NULL
0:00:00 504.0772095 502.510498  19.74362946 NULL
0:00:03 506.5715942 501.0021973 18.33575058 NULL
0:00:06 506.9558105 500.8230896 18.01424026 NULL
0:00:09 507.637085  502.4645996 18.22068024 NULL
0:01:00 503.7373962 500.0382996 19.65225029 NULL
0:01:03 501.9363098 498.4442139 18.83662987 NULL
0:01:06 501.2966919 498.635498  18.13269043 NULL
0:01:09 501.3804932 499.8033142 18.47451019 NULL
0:01:12 501.2026062 502.9010925 18.27821922 NULL
0:01:15 500.9111938 504.7002869 18.64034081 NULL
0:01:57 499.8942871 503.0549927 19.3476696  NULL
0:02:00 500.7025146 503.311615  18.45420074 NULL
0:02:03 500.3114929 504.3681946 19.56426048 NULL
0:02:06 499.1243896 505.3652039 18.55912018 NULL
0:02:09 499.8727112 507.0862122 19.55410957 NULL
0:02:12 500.377594  507.8305969 18.19698906 NULL
0:03:00 499.7817993 506.4544983 18.27145004 NULL
0:03:03 499.6297913 505.3894958 18.03116035 NULL
0:03:06 499.1319885 503.8894043 19.45935059 NULL
0:03:09 497.7235107 502.6158142 19.35782051 NULL
0:04:00 498.6130066 NULL    19.00246048 NULL
0:04:03 498.3045959 NULL    18.31543922 NULL
0:04:06 498.9266052 NULL    20.20389938 NULL
0:04:09 500.3635864 NULL    18.74864006 NULL
0:04:12 501.0609131 NULL    18.34589958 NULL
0:05:00 502.0812073 502.6158142 19.80117035 NULL
0:06:00 503.0812073 NULL    20.80117035 4
0:07:00 503.0812073 NULL    21.80117035 NULL
0:08:00 NULL    NULL    22.80117035 NULL
0:09:00 NULL    506.6158142 23.80117035 NULL
0:10:00 503.0812073 NULL    24.80117035 NULL
............................................
```

So after clubbing every last 5 minutes data and selecting only last not null values from that time period output will look like :

```
DateTime    A          B            C        D
0:05:00 502.0812073 502.6158142 19.80117035 NULL
0:10:00 503.0812073 506.6158142 24.80117035 4
.........
```

So output will be having records for every 5 minutes(0:05:00, 0:10:00, 0:15:00, 0:20:00, .... maximum date range we can have)

If any column has all `NULL` values in the last 5 minutes interval, then we can also have the `NULL` value in the output for that interval.

Any Idea for how to group these data? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To get last non null values every five minutes:

```py
df = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.DateTime).dt.ceil("5min"), as_index=False).last()
```

With your sample data you will get 3 rows:

|  | DateTime | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0:00:00 | 504.077209 | 502.510498 | 19.743629 | NaN |
| 1 | 0:05:00 | 502.081207 | 502.615814 | 19.801170 | NaN |
| 2 | 0:10:00 | 503.081207 | 506.615814 | 24.801170 | 4.0 |

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if I have DateTime column format as `2021-03-30 00:00:00` and I want the output with a `DateTime` column format like`2021-03-30 00:00:00, 2021-03-30 00:05:00, 2021-03-30 00:10:00, 2021-03-30 00:20:00, .....` and so on.

Comment: If the DateTime column already have that format, the same code will do.